# Redirect to another site after login is not working

Tags: asp.net, html, thickbox, response.redirect

We have an already running `asp.net` web site (lets call it example.com). In our new site (mostly HTML pages) we call login page from old site using `thickbox` like following:

```
<a href="http://example.com/login.aspx?keepThis=true&TB_iframe=true&" 
             class="thickbox">login</a>
```

login.aspx is a simple page with two fields (id, pwd) and a login button. On login button's handler following code is run after validating the credentials:

```
response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'> 
         top.location.href='example.com/usermain.aspx'</script>");
```

On clicking login link it successfully loads login.aspx page in thickbox., but after logging in (clicking **login** button) in **IE 8** it always redirect to **http://example.com/index.aspx** which is default home page for site (for guest/anonym visitrs). If I am using **Firefox** it properly redirects to **http://example.com/usermain.aspx** most of the times.

Please help me find out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: use `parent.location` instead of `top.location.href`

Comment: If only there were some [domain name that was specific reserved for examples...](http://www.iana.org/domains/example/)  Oh, wait

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn :D did'nt get you at first...

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.location.assign(url)` instead.

Comment: I'm opening this in thickbox will it be able to get to parent.location?

Comment: nope no help. in thick box `window.location.assign` just opens page in thickbox window.

Comment: That is because it is a frame... You need to have the frame lose focus first most likely